# How to add imagebuttons to gridview in android

Tags: java, android, gridview, imagebutton

I can not figure out how to add imagebuttons to my gridview. I have to have individual code to execute for each imagebutton, because they do completely different things. How can I do it?

I ended up using a tablelayout instead

Code:

```
package com.mysoftware.mysoftwareos.launcher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Import views

        //Setup onClickListener for the buttons

        //Setup GridView
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        //Do nothing to prevent the back button to kill the launcher
        return true;
        }
    return super.onKeyDown(KeyCode, event);
    }

    public void onClick(View src) {
        switch(src.getId()) {
        }
    }
}
```

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FF8090A0" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/appsGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the code you're using to show your gridview.

Comment: I really dont got that much code, but i have uploaded it for you to see

Comment: gridviews require some kind of adapter. if you don't have one, then that would be step one.

Comment: I see an emtpy GridView in your XML layout. What have you tried in order to add the buttons to it?

Comment: I ended up using a tablelayout instead, thanks for the idea, really grateful about the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gridview has an onitemclickedlistener you can use, but if the buttons are supposed to do different things, and you aren't loading from some kind of data store, you probably don't want a gridview anyway. look into the DashboardLayout from Roman Nurik a couple years ago. You can just add the ImageButtons to it either in XML or code. If you add in code, you can assign each button an anonymous onClickListener. If you do it in XML you can set the onClick attribute to a method in your activity.

Comment: I ended up using a tablelayout instead, thanks for the idea, really grateful about the answers

Comment: that works. i like the dashboard layout because it automatically lays children out in an evenly spaced grid. it has some bugs, but it works pretty well - up to 6 buttons.